# Force re-render of vuejs component that is mounted programaticaly (can't use :key ?)

Tags: vue.js, dom, state

I an app that has both old school javascript and vue.js components, I am mounting my vue.js components in the dom using `new Vue([...]).$mount(elementName)`.

But sometime, I would like to completly reset the components (clean local state, and go through the lifecycle hooks again). The problem is that my `elementName` does not exist anymore, it has been transformed to the vue.js component.

If my component was inserted into the dom using vue.js template itself (`<my-component [...] />`), I would simply use a `:key` to force vue to re-render the component. But because of the aproach defined above, I am confused on how to do that the best way possible.

I could always watch for a value inside my component, and have some kind of `resetState` method, but this is realy something I am trying to avoid, for maintenance reasons (many components, many of them will evolve, seems like a good way to miss something one day).

Comment: You can unmount and mount again in the scope where 'new Vue' is called. *for obvious reasons* - they aren't obvious, it's a suitable way.

Comment: @EstusFlask, I have edited my question concerning the "obvious reasons", you are right it was vague.
I wanted to know if there is a cleaner way than mount/unmount (and the process of recreating dom elements programaticaly to do so), but maybe it does not exist.

Comment: It's not a bad practice to have a convention over init method that resets component state, can be useful in several scenarios where a component can't or shouldn't be remounted, e.g. on route update. As for `new Vue`, it's the point where a component is mounted, so it should be remounted there too. You can make a wrapper if it's a common task.